# [Plain javascript]My mouseover effect is buggy

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I'm trying to achieve a mouse hover effect using Js on three `<li>`s.
The effect doesn't work on the first try, I have to keep hovering my mouse again and again to go back to its original string.

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

note: i linked the script at the right before `</body>`

HTML code:

```html
<ul>
  <li data-value="// ABOUT"    ><a href="#" >// ABOUT    </a></li>
  <li data-value="// PROJECTS" ><a href='#' >// PROJECTS </a></li>
  <li data-value="// CONTACT" ><a href="#"  >// CONTACT  </a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code:

```
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => {
  li.onmouseover = event => {
    let iteration = 0;

    clearInterval(interval);

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
        .split("")
        .map((letter, index) => {
          if (index < iteration) {
            return event.target.dataset.value[index];
          }

          return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)];
        })
        .join("");

      if (iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

      iteration += 1 / 3;
    }, 30);
  };
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a single `interval` variable for *all* the `<li>` elements on the page.

Comment: Move the `let interval = null;` line to *inside* the `.forEach()` callback, right before the `li.onmouseover` line.

Comment: @Pointy
putting the let `interval = null;` inside the `.forEach()` callback seems to fix the 3rd bug however, it's now taking more time to iterate before going back to original.

Comment: at the end you remove the `<a href="#" ... </a>` and replace them only by text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- you don't need to use `event.target` because you only use arrow function.
2- the `interval` variable should be local to avoid conflicts in your multiples `setInterval`
3- your code remove all links -> ex `<li><a href="#" >// ABOUT </a><li>` by  `<li>// ABOUT <li>`....

so, here it is... ( with some improvemnts )

```js
const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach( li_Elm => 
  {
  let interval = null
    , li_aLink = li_Elm.querySelector('a')
    , textInit = li_aLink.textContent 
    , length   = textInit.length
    ;
  li_Elm.onmouseover =_=> 
    {
    let iteration = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(() =>
      {
      li_aLink.textContent = Array
        .from( ({length}), (letter,index) => 
        ( index < iteration) 
                ? textInit[index]
                : letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
        ).join('');

      if (iteration >= length)
        clearInterval(interval);

      iteration += 1 / 3;
      }
      , 30);
    };
  });
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" >// ABOUT    </a></li>
    <li><a href='#' >// PROJECTS </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >// CONTACT  </a></li>
  </ul>
```